# Помогите исправить ошибки в коде с++, задание закреплено

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class Person {
private:
    char* name, * surname;
    unsigned int name_s, surname_s;
    int city_id, interior_number;
public:
    Person();
    Person(char[], char[], int, int);
    Person(Person&);
    ~Person() { delete[] name; delete[] surname; };

    Person& changeName(char[]);
    char* getName() { return this->name; };

    Person& changeSurname(char[]);
    char* getSurname() { return this->surname; };

    Person& changeCityId(int new_city_id) { this->city_id = new_city_id; return *this; };
    int getCityId() const { return this->city_id; };

    Person& changeInteriorNumber(int new_int_num) { this->interior_number = new_int_num; return *this; };
    int getInteriorNumber() const { return this->interior_number; };

    void printFullInfo() { cout << "Person: " << this->getName() << "   " << this->getSurname() << "   " << "+380" << this->getCityId() << this->getInteriorNumber() << endl; }
};
Person::Person() : name_s(1), surname_s(1), city_id(0), interior_number(0) {
    this->name = new char[this->name_s];
    strcpy(this->name, "");
    this->surname = new char[this->surname_s];
    strcpy(this->surname, "");
}
Person::Person(char name[], char surname[], int city_id, int interior_number) : name_s(strlen(name) + 1), surname_s(strlen(surname) + 1), city_id(city_id), interior_number(interior_number) {
    this->name = new char[this->name_s];
    strcpy(this->name, name);
    this->surname = new char[this->surname_s];
    strcpy(this->surname, surname);
}
Person::Person(Person& h) : name_s(h.name_s), surname_s(h.surname_s), city_id(h.city_id), interior_number(h.interior_number) {
    this->name = new char[this->name_s];
    strcpy(this->name, h.name);
    this->surname = new char[this->surname_s];
    strcpy(this->surname, h.surname);
}
Person& Person::changeName(char new_name[]) {
    delete[] this->name;
    this->name_s = strlen(new_name) + 1;
    this->name = new char[this->name_s];
    strcpy(this->name, new_name);
    return *this;
}
Person& Person::changeSurname(char new_surname[]) {
    delete[] this->surname;
    this->surname_s = strlen(new_surname) + 1;
    this->surname = new char[this->surname_s];
    strcpy(this->surname, new_surname);
    return *this;
};

class Competitor {
private:
    char* country, * sport;
    unsigned int country_s, sport_s;
    Person trainer;
    int number;
public:
    Competitor();
    Competitor(char[], char[], Person&, int);
    Competitor(Competitor&);
    ~Competitor() { delete[] country; delete[] sport; };

    Competitor& changeCountry(char[]);
    char* getCountry() { return this->country; };

    Competitor& changeSport(char[]);
    char* getSport() { return this->sport; };

    Competitor& changeTrainer(Person& new_trainer) { this->trainer = Person(new_trainer); return *this; };
    Person getTrainer() { return this->trainer; };

    Competitor& changeNumber(int new_number) { this->number = new_number; return *this; };
    int getNumber() const { return this->number; };

    void printFullInfo();
    void printShortInfo() const { cout << "Competitor: " << this->getNumber(); };
};
Competitor::Competitor() : country_s(1), sport_s(1), number(0) {
    this->country = new char[this->country_s];
    strcpy(this->country, "");
    this->sport = new char[this->sport_s];
    strcpy(this->sport, "");
    this->trainer = Person();
}
Competitor::Competitor(char country[], char sport[], Person& trainer, int number) : country_s(strlen(country) + 1), sport_s(strlen(sport) + 1), trainer(trainer), number(number) {
    this->country = new char[this->country_s];
    strcpy(this->country, country);
    this->sport = new char[this->sport_s];
    strcpy(this->sport, sport);
}
Competitor::Competitor(Competitor& c) : country_s(c.country_s), sport_s(c.sport_s), trainer(c.trainer), number(c.number) {
    country = new char[this->country_s];
    strcpy(country, c.country);
    sport = new char[this->sport_s];
    strcpy(sport, c.sport);
}
Competitor& Competitor::changeCountry(char new_country[]) {
    delete[] this->country;
    this->country_s = strlen(new_country) + 1;
    this->country = new char[this->country_s];
    strcpy(this->country, new_country);
    return *this;
}
Competitor& Competitor::changeSport(char new_sport[]) {
    delete[] this->sport;
    this->sport_s = strlen(new_sport) + 1;
    this->sport = new char[this->sport_s];
    strcpy(this->sport, new_sport);
    return *this;
}

void Competitor::printFullInfo() {
    cout << "Competitor: " << this->getCountry() << "   " << this->getSport() << "   ";
    cout << "   " << this->getNumber() << endl;
};

class FootballClub :public Competitor
{
private:
    double goals;
    char* result;
    double sequence_number;
public:
    FootballClub();
    FootballClub(char[], char[], int, int, double, char*, double);
    FootballClub(FootballClub&);
    ~FootballClub();

    FootballClub& changeGoals(double new_goals) { this->goals = new_goals; return *this; };
    double getGoals() const { return this->goals; };

    FootballClub& changeResult(char* new_result) { this->result = new_result; return *this; };
    char* getResult() const { return this->result; };

    FootballClub& changeSequence_number(double new_sequence_number) { this->sequence_number = new_sequence_number; return *this; };
    double getSequence_number() const { return this->sequence_number; };

    void printFullInfo();
};

void FootballClub::printFullInfo() {
    cout << "FootballClub: " << this->getGoals() << "   " << this->getResult() << "   ";
};

class Athlete :public Competitor
{
private:
    double time_a;
    double timeLeader;
    double bTheLeader;
    char* place;
public:
    Athlete();
    Athlete(char[], char[], int, int, double, double, double, double);
    Athlete(Athlete&);
    ~Athlete();

    Athlete& changeTime_a(double new_time_a) { this->time_a = new_time_a; return *this; };
    double getTime() { return this->time_a; };

    Athlete& changeTimeLeader(double new_timeLeader) { this->timeLeader = new_timeLeader; return *this; };
    double getTimeLeader() { return this->timeLeader; };

    Athlete& changeBehindTheLeader(double new_bTheLeader) { this->bTheLeader = new_bTheLeader; return *this; };
    double getBTheLeader() { return this->bTheLeader; };

    Athlete& changePlace(char* new_place) { this->place = new_place; return *this; };
    char* getPlace() { return this->place; };

    void printFullInfo();
};

void Athlete::printFullInfo() {
    cout << "Athlete: " << this->getTime() << "   " << this->getTimeLeader() << "   " << this->getBTheLeader() << "   " << this->getPlace() << "  " << endl;
   
};



int main() {
     char name[20], surname[20], country[20], sport[20], result[20];
    int city_id, interior_number, number;
    double goals, sequence_number, time_a, timeLeader, behindTheLeader, place;

    cout << "First: " << endl << "   Name: "; cin >> name;
    cout << "   Surname: "; cin >> surname;
    cout << "   City ID: "; cin >> city_id;
    cout << "   Int. number: "; cin >> interior_number;

    Person first(name, surname, city_id, interior_number);

    cout << "   Country: "; cin >> country;
    cout << "   Sport: "; cin >> sport;
    cout << "   Number: "; cin >> number;

    Competitor first_m(country, sport, first, number);

    first.printFullInfo();
    first_m.printFullInfo();
    first_m.printShortInfo();

    cout << "Now you can work with the first pair of derivate Class FootballClub and Athlete" << endl;

    cout << "   Goals: "; cin >> goals;
    cout << "   Result: "; cin >> result;
    cout << "   Sequence_number: "; cin >> sequence_number;

    FootballClub first_c(name, surname, city_id, interior_number, goals, result, sequence_number);

    cout << "   Time: "; cin >> time_a;
    cout << "   TimeLeader: "; cin >> timeLeader;
    cout << "   BehindTheLeader: "; cin >> behindTheLeader;
    cout << "   Place:   "; cin >> place;

    Athlete first_v(name, surname, city_id, interior_number, time_a, timeLeader, behindTheLeader, place);

    first_c.printFullInfo();
    first_v.printFullInfo();

    cout << endl;


    Person second;

    second.changeName("John");
    second.changeSurname("Johnson");
    second.changeCityId(70);
    second.changeInteriorNumber(1443077);

    Competitor second_m;

    second_m.changeCountry("Ukraine");
    second_m.changeSport("Baseball");
    second_m.changeTrainer(second);
    second_m.changeNumber(222);

    FootballClub second_a;

    second_a.changeGoals(15);
    second_a.changeResult("win");
    second_a.changeSequence_number(6);

    Athlete second_b;
    second_b.changeTime_a(275);
    second_b.changeTimeLeader(200);
    second_b.changeBehindTheLeader(75);
    second_b.changePlace("third");



    second.printFullInfo();
    second_m.printFullInfo();
    second_m.printShortInfo();
    second_a.printFullInfo();
    second_b.printFullInfo();
    cout << endl;


    Person third(first);

    third = third.changeName("Vasya");
    third = third.changeInteriorNumber(1453077);

    Competitor third_m(first_m);

    third_m = third_m.changeTrainer(third);
    third_m = third_m.changeNumber(333);

    FootballClub trird_a;

    trird_a.changeGoals(25);
    trird_a.changeResult("lose");
    trird_a.changeSequence_number(4);

    Athlete trird_b;

    trird_b.changeTime_a(300);
    trird_b.changeTimeLeader(200);
    trird_b.changeBehindTheLeader(100);
    trird_b.changePlace("fifth");


    third.printFullInfo();
    third_m.printFullInfo();
    third_m.printShortInfo();
    trird_a.printFullInfo();
    trird_b.printFullInfo();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: а нужно использовать именно char* и сишные функции или можно писать на обычном с++ с применением std::string?

Comment: А вообще в чём ошибка заключается? Не могли бы Вы привести её пример?

Comment: в SetName и SetSurname лучше добавить слово const для параметра. А также отсутствуют реализации конструкторов/деструкторов. Либо их не добавили, либо в этом и заключается ошибка.

Comment: Хотя, если видеть логи на консоли, то забыли добавить конструкторы и деструкторы для практически всех производных классов. Ну и ещё начиная с C++11 система будет предупреждать о несовместимости std::string и char *

Comment: @KoVadim Можно писать на обычном с++, делал как знал :D Не могли бы вы чуть более детально рассказать как реализовать конструкторы/деструкторы ссылаясь на мой код, буду благодарен!

Comment: Как только будете использовать std::string вместо сишных строк - все сильно-сильно упроститься.

Comment: @4500zenja компилятор выдаёт "невозможно преобразовать const char[] в char*". Так же ему совсем не нравится strcpy.

Comment: @KoVadim Возможно мой вопрос прозвучит глупо, но я совсем зелёный в программировании, по этому задам, нужно заменить все char на string? Функции как-то изменяться или особенно нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начнем по коду. Правило номер один - не использовать `using namespace std;` глобально. В хедерах - только если хочется навредить, в начале cpp файла - если полная лень. Если и использовать то в ограниченной области (scope).

Дальше - `char*` для строк - признак сишного кода. Лучше использовать std::string. Для "строк в кавычках" следует использовать `const char*`, а не `char*` если уже пришлось.

Как только перешли на std::string, то вдруг уже не нужно new/delete и подобное.

И теперь геттер превращается в такое

```
const std::string& getName() { return this->name; };
```

(да используется ссылка на константную строку, что бы избежать лишних копирований. Но это такой популярный паттерн, что руки пишут и не заморачиваются).

Посмотрим ещё на это

```
char* name, surname;
unsigned int name_s, surname_s;
```

я вначале смотрел что это за две переменные, но потом понял, что это длины строк выше. И это на самом деле БОЛЬШАЯ проблема в этом коде - за одну сущность (строка) отвечает две отдельные, не связанные между собой, переменные. Это почти всегда приводит к проблемам. Если уже пишется чисто си код, то можно сделать структуру под это, но у нас есть `std::string`, который знает свою длину!

Посмотрите, как теперь стал выглядеть первый класс

```
class Person {
private:
    std::string name, surname;
    int city_id, interior_number;
public:
    Person();
    Person(const char* name, const char* surname, int city_id, int interior_number);
    Person(Person&);
    ~Person() { };

    Person& changeName(const char* new_name);
    const std::string& getName() { return this->name; };

    Person& changeSurname(const char* new_surname);
    const std::string& getSurname() { return this->surname; };

    Person& changeCityId(int new_city_id) { this->city_id = new_city_id; return *this; };
    int getCityId() const { return this->city_id; };

    Person& changeInteriorNumber(int new_int_num) { this->interior_number = new_int_num; return *this; };
    int getInteriorNumber() const { return this->interior_number; };

    void printFullInfo() { std::cout << "Person: " << getName() << "   " << getSurname() << "   " << "+380" << getCityId() << this->getInteriorNumber() << std::endl; }
};
Person::Person() : name(""), surname(""), city_id(0), interior_number(0) {
}
Person::Person(const char* name, const char* surname, int city_id, int interior_number) : name(name), surname(surname), city_id(city_id), interior_number(interior_number) {
}
Person::Person(Person& h) : name(h.name), surname(h.surname), city_id(h.city_id), interior_number(h.interior_number) {
}
Person& Person::changeName(const char* new_name) {
    this->name = new_name;
    return *this;
}
Person& Person::changeSurname(const char* new_surname) {
    this->surname = new_surname;
    return *this;
};
```

Но даже в этом коде есть куча проблем. Во первых, конструкторы "генерированые ручками", это и компилятор может написать. А во вторых, есть правило 3/5 (или его сейчас уже называют правилом X) - если есть написанный конструктор копирования, то должен быть и оператор копирования. Можно это написать (и пока были char* это нужно было писать), то теперь можно доверить все компилятору. Вуаля:

```
class Person {
private:
    std::string name, surname;
    int city_id, interior_number;
public:
    Person() = default;
    Person(const char* name, const char* surname, int city_id, int interior_number);
    Person(Person&) = default;
    Person& operator=(const Person&) = default;
    ~Person() = default;

    Person& changeName(const char* new_name);
    const std::string& getName() { return this->name; };

    Person& changeSurname(const char* new_surname);
    const std::string& getSurname() { return this->surname; };

    Person& changeCityId(int new_city_id) { this->city_id = new_city_id; return *this; };
    int getCityId() const { return this->city_id; };

    Person& changeInteriorNumber(int new_int_num) { this->interior_number = new_int_num; return *this; };
    int getInteriorNumber() const { return this->interior_number; };

    void printFullInfo() { std::cout << "Person: " << getName() << "   " << getSurname() << "   " << "+380" << getCityId() << this->getInteriorNumber() << std::endl; }
};

Person::Person(const char* name, const char* surname, int city_id, int interior_number) : name(name), surname(surname), city_id(city_id), interior_number(interior_number) {
}

Person& Person::changeName(const char* new_name) {
    this->name = new_name;
    return *this;
}
Person& Person::changeSurname(const char* new_surname) {
    this->surname = new_surname;
    return *this;
};
```

ну красивее же? и кода меньше и ошибок меньше. Тут есть спорный кусочек

```
Person& changeName(const char* new_name);
```

возможно, лучше его переписать вот так

```
Person& changeName(const std::string& new_name);
```

А может... ещё и move сементику прикрутить (но сможет ли преподаватель?).

Аналогично переписывается и все другое. Единственное, на что я бы обратил внимание - это то, что Competitor - базовый класс, и деструктор лучше сделать виртуальным.

Comment: Спасибо большое за такой ответ, очень благодарен!